# Rewrite Except Without Distinct

Tags: sql, t-sql

Since `EXCEPT` is a Set Operation, it automatically makes its results distinct. How can I rewrite a query like the following without the result containing only distinct values?

```
SELECT T1.ContainerName, T1.PanelName FROM MyTable AS T1
EXCEPT
SELECT T2.ContainerName, T2.PanelName FROM MyOtherTable AS T2
```

Given the first `SELECT` results as follows:

```
Container1    MyPanel
Container1    MyPanel
Container2    MyPanel
Container3    MyPanel
```

and the second `SELECT` returning as follows:

```
Container3    MyPanel
```

then the above `EXCEPT` query will return:

```
Container1    MyPanel
Container2    MyPanel
```

Since the names matter and we're able to have duplicate names as I've done above, it's important that I have both listings of `Container1    MyPanel` in my final result list.

So the question is, in a general sense, how can this `EXCEPT` query be transformed into a query that will not specify `DISTINCT` results?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking to see the difference between the two results without excluding duplicates in the final result set.

The final result I WANT is as follows:

```
Container1    MyPanel
Container1    MyPanel
Container2    MyPanel
```

Comment: replace `EXCEPT` with `UNION ALL` would be my first guess

Comment: I believe UNION ALL will return records from both, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it will, but OP asked specifically about how to do it so it does not return distinct rows

Comment: True, but also based on the post, the OP did want to exclude Container3, without forcing a distinct through the EXCEPT.   Ironically, I thought the same thing too, and had to reread the post.

Comment: Sorry for confusion! Is there any way I can make the question clearer for future readers? The idea is to see the difference between the two results without excluding duplicates.

Comment: @TinyHaitian yea I was unsure about that as well that is why I only posted it as a comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want everything from `mytable` where there is no corresponding row in `myothertable`.  Sounds like a job for `exists()`.  Try:-

```
select t1.ContainerName, t1.PanelName
from MyTable t1
where not exists(
    select * FROM MyOtherTable t2
    where t2.ContainerName=t1.ContainerName
        and t2.PanelName=t1.PanelName
)
```

If you can use the PK of `myothertable` (assuming it's an FK in `mytable`) you can simplify the `where` in the sub query.

Comment: This is the one that seems to work for what I need while at the same time making it very clear what it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

how about `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    MyTable1 AS t1
        LEFT JOIN MyTable2 AS t2
            ON t1.ContainerName = t2.ContainerName 
               AND t1.PanelName = t2.PanelName
WHERE   t2.PanelName  IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58c1ca/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to the second table on the same values, and only return the results from the first table where they're not also in the second:

```
SELECT T1.ContainerName, T1.PanelName 
FROM MyTable AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyOtherTable AS T2 ON T2.ContainerName = T1.ContainerName 
    AND T2.PanelName = T1.PanelName
WHERE T2.ContainerName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I like John Woo's answer listed below better, but thought I'd be a devil's advocate and try a different route, just for example's sake. You could also try this:

```
 select * from MyTable1
 where ContainerName not in (
   select ContainerName from MyTable2)
```

[Check Sql Fiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58c1ca/8)

Comment: This wouldn't work if trying to match more than one column. For example, if I wanted to check if (Container1,MyPanel) existed in the subquery, how would I specify that? I suppose I could, in the subquery, select the pair concatenated (perhaps with a delimiter) like so: `WHERE CONCAT(ContainerName,'~',PanelName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(ContainerName,'~',PanelName) FROM MyTable2...`

Comment: True, and if that's the case, you would probably need to use a NOT EXISTS option, as someone else suggested below.   No need to concatenate though, in this case.

Comment: Correct, I just figured there had to be a way to use what you were saying. Concatenating seemed like a weird workaround that did actually work. But I'll be going with the `NOT EXISTS` option I think. Thanks!~

Answer (score 0):

```
select containername,panelname 
from mytable where containername in(
    select containername from(
      SELECT T1.ContainerName, T1.PanelName FROM MyTable AS T1
      EXCEPT
      SELECT T2.ContainerName, T2.PanelName FROM MyOtherTable AS T2
      )a
)
```

Comment: Might be a bit overkill too, but I suppose it could work.  I'd look at the execution plan of this one over the others listed.

Comment: At this point it'w not working yet. It works for your example, but add a Container1 in MyOtherTable and it fails.

Comment: All right now I think I got it working, a lot shorter than the previous version :)

Comment: I'd have to test too (just curious), but looks a bit easier to read too.  :)